# Data validation for multiple user inputs with Python

Tags: python, validation, for-loop, while-loop

I am creating a function for my python course that receives a list and returns the same list without the smallest number. However, I wanted to extend the function to ask the user for inputs to create the list after performing some data validations on the inputs.

I was able to validate the first input. However, I got stuck at the second data validation as I need to guarantee that the program should accept only integers in the list and throw and prompt the user again for every wrong input something like while not (type(number) == int) which breaks as soon as the user input matches an int.

How should I do this?

```py
def smallest():
    
    # This function asks the user for a list
    # and returns the same list without the smallest number or numbers
    
    list_range = 'Not a number'
    list_created = []
    
    while not (type(list_range) == int):
        try:
            list_range = int(input('Please enter the total number of elements for your list:  '))
            
        except:
            print('Please provide a number!')
  

    for number in range(1,list_range + 1):
        try:
            list_element = int(input('Please enter the value of the %d element: ' %number))
            list_created.append(list_element)
        
        except:
            print('Please provide a number!')
                
    smallest = min(list_created)
    result = []
    
    for num in list_created:
        if num != smallest:
            result.append(num)
            
    return result
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a while loop until an `int` value is entered:

```
for number in range(1, list_range + 1):
    while True:
        list_element = input('Please enter the value of the %d element: ' % number)
        try:
            list_element = int(list_element)
            list_created.append(list_element)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Please provide a number!')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried the while loop before the for loop. Obviously non sense as the validation was need for each iteration.

Comment: Glad to help. If that solved your issue completely, you may want to accept this answer by clicking the checkmark next to it. This will yield some reputation for the answerer, and you, the asker. You don't have to do this.